# Can Si PMIC controller gate outputs drive GaN Drivers?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, gan

I have a boost converter design based on an LM5022 PMIC incorporating a 1A gate driver. I'm looking to experiment with a GaN IC and driver (1EDN71x6U), which specifies that it's expecting logic-level input voltages of 3.3 or 5V. Given my gate driver outputs up to 8V, can I signal condition with a fast switching diode (to avoid negative crossover) and a voltage divider, or would the signal conditioning need to be more complex and say, implement an opamp?

At what point does it make more sense to seek out alternative controllers? All the switching PMICs that I've come across appear to only have gate driven outputs.

Comment: Sorry--what are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to feed the driver's output into a logic input??

Comment: @Hearth exactly.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: PWM controllers with integrated gate drivers are cheap and freely available. Coupling a simple PWM boost controller IC with a GaN gate drive and GaN FET would make for a simple and fairly elegant, cost effective solution

Comment: Okay, but why do you want to put that output into a logic input? Gate driver outputs go to FET gates, not to logic inputs.

Comment: I don't belive I'll be able to drive a GaN FET witha Si FET driver and instead require a GaN driver

Comment: If you stay within the FET's limits, it doesn't matter if the driver says it's for GaN parts or not. Though it's common that you want to drive a WBG device's gate below ground when turning it off; most of the time, you'll need a different driver design to do that.

Comment: GaN can likely be driven from Si drivers, using a suitable coupling network; values will depend on supply voltage, relative ratings, and etc. In this case, LM5022 operates down to 5 or 6V, which might be acceptable with direct connection to a GaN gate.